# How to run single controller method from any route in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, routes

I really hope my question has been well thought out but here goes.
How do you implement something like

```
Route::get("/url1", "controller@method");
Route::get("hello/url1", "controller@method");
Route::get("hello/hi/url1", "controller@method");
```

in Laravel but using something like

```
Route::get("*/url1", "controller@method");
```

instead of declaring every route path?

I will explain why this problem has come up. You see the primary url is always changing because its being called from a js file via a `location.href` call. I could decide to use a primary url variable but its to be deployed via intranet to different servers in organizations and the primary url could change at any time meaning that `localhost/project` on one system might become `localhost:7987/project` on another thus breaking the url variable, now thats on one part. On the other hand there are js functions running continuously and when someone navigates to a deeper url, say from `localhost/home` to `localhost/home/event` a route call that should be independent of folder breaks

So yeah, I am wondering if theres a way to declare a global route that points to a controller and/or if this is possible in Laravel.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Route::get('{something}/url1', 'controller@method')->where('something', '*');
```

Not sure if that will work, but the idea is that you can use `where` to pass some Regexp to match selected value from route.

Comment: Ended up using something like 

`Route::get('{something}/url1', 'controller@method')->where('something', '(.*)'); 

but thanks alot